# Laravel - Nested relation causes previous filters to be ignored

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I do a specific relation query all over the application, where I only need the User's `subscriptions` that have `active` column set to `true`.

And I have a `scope` method in `User` model, which applies said filter, to avoid copy/paste, like:

```
public function scopeWithActiveSubscriptions($query)
{
    $query->with([
        'subscriptions' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('active', true);
        },
    ]);
}
```

---

Now sometimes I want to eager-load the `plan` of each `subscription`, too.

For that I tried something like:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)
    ->withActiveSubscriptions()
    ->with('subscriptions.plan')
    ->first();

$subscriptionList = $user->subscriptions;
```

But query results to **all** subscriptions,
in other words, ignores the `->where('active', true)` part (of `scope` method).

How can I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be modifying the `scopeWithActiveSubscriptions` method to allow it to accept another optional parameter that tells it which additional relations should also be included and thus you don't loose your filtering.

```
public function scopeWithActiveSubscriptions($query, array $with = [])
{
    // just merges hard coded subscription filtering with the supplied relations from $with parameter
    $query->with(array_merge([
        'subscriptions' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('active', true);
        }
    ], $with));
}
```

Now you can tell that scope which nested relations you want to include and you no longer need to call `with` to include them by yourself.

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)
    ->withActiveSubscriptions(['subscriptions.plan'])
    // ->with('subscriptions.plan') // no longer needed as we're telling the scope to do that for us
    ->first();

$subscriptionList = $user->subscriptions;
```

With that you can pass custom relations to the scope something like *(am improvising here just for demo purposes)*

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)
    ->withActiveSubscriptions([
        'subscriptions.plan' => fn($q) => $q->where('plans.type', 'GOLD')
    ])->first();
```

> Learn more about [Laravel's Eloquent Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes).

Hope i have pushed you further.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) I will accept this later, in hope of someone knowing an even better Laravel *magic*.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Laravel does not have yet any *chainable* (Builder-style) solution (for asked situation), and we ended up editing the `scope` filter.

Into something like:

```php
public function scopeWithPendingSubscriptions(Builder $query, $subRelations = null)
{
    $query->with([
        'subscriptions' => function (HasMany $query) use ($subRelations) {
            $query->where('active', '=', true);
            if ($subRelations) {
                $query->with($subRelations);
            }
        },
    ]);
}
```

Which allows me to do query like:

```php
// ...
->withActiveSubscriptions('plan');
```

Instead of my old (not working) code, which was:

```php
// ...
->withActiveSubscriptions()
->with('subscriptions.plan');
```

> **Note** that even passing nested-filters is now possible, like:
>
> ```
> // ...
> ->withActiveSubscriptions(['plan' => function ($query) {
>    $query->where('name');
> }]);
> ```
>
> (Basically same as Laravel's `->with(...)` method.)